# Creating "stick controls" for android game?

Tags: java, android, game-physics

I'm trying to create a simple Android game, a 2D action shooter which has 2 control sticks (circles) on the screen, the left one is movement control and the right one weapon control. Direction is being controlled by the position of your thumb relative to the circle’s center.

I've been following a tutorial on this site: http://www.kilobolt.com/day-7-creating-an-android-game-from-start-to-finish.html but it only gave me the base to work on. I have no programming experience so I'm quite lost now.

I got the movement working only on TOUCH_DOWN event, the hero moves to about where it should but to change direction I have to lift my thumb and touch the circle again. TOUCH_DRAGGED (or ACTION_MOVE) is broken because if I drag my finger across the circle the character moves really fast. I guess the problem is too many touch events are being handled, but I have no idea how to fix it.

How can I change this so that I can drag my thumb around the circle and the hero will change its direction instantly, and keep its speed constant all the time? Also the speed should be the same no matter how close or far from the center of the circle you touch.

```
private void updateRunning(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents, float deltaTime) {

    int len = touchEvents.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);  
        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN || event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DRAGGED) {

            if (inBounds(event, 50, 300, 150, 150, 'c')) {
                ctrl.setX(event.x);
                ctrl.setY(event.y);
                ctrl.direction();
                hero.move(ctrl.getDirX(), ctrl.getDirY());
            }
        }

        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {

            if (inBounds(event, 0, 0, 35, 35,'r')) {
                pause();
            }
            hero.stopMove();
        }   
    }

    hero.update();
```

The movement: hero's speedX and speedY are added to hero's centerX and centerY on every hero.update() call.

```
public void move(float x, float y) {

    speedX += x * MOVESPEED;
    speedY += y * MOVESPEED;

}
```

This method that handles the x & y speed. Found it here at stackoverflow, and because touch_down event is working ok, I guess it's doing it's job. Although I feel it's not exactly how it's supposed to be. L_STICK_C is a constant with values of 100 and 350 (center of the circle).

```
public void direction() {

        dir.x = x - L_STICK_C.x;
        dir.y = y - L_STICK_C.y;
        double hyp = Math.sqrt(dir.x * dir.x + dir.y * dir.y);
        dir.x = (float) (dir.x / hyp);
        dir.y = (float) (dir.y / hyp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into some game programming tutorials.  You usually would not move the character directly from the touch input. You'd set a game state variable once a game loop which would correspond to the position of your thumb inputs.  Then you'd only update the hero once per game loop based on those inputs.  This lets allows you to keep the game input control code, and hero code separate, and makes it re-usable for other parts of your game.

EDIT:

Based on your code, every time you drag your finger, you generate a bunch of dragged events.  So you are adding onto your characters speed for each event.  You should probably just be looking at the distance to center and x / y of the input on the last touch event, not all of them.

Comment: Oops, i see you are looking at a tutorail, my bad.